# I want to read in a hex file into a array 4 bytes at a time

Tags: c++, c

Title says it all. For this application i want to input a file which contains all hex values and have it split it up into 4 bytes sections. then have those inputted into a linked list or array for later manipulation. For some reason my function isn't working correctly any ideas how to make it work correctly?

```
void readapp(){
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned char buffer[512];
     FILE *file;
    char *fileOutput;
    char outname = "/home/user/blah";
    file = fopen( outname, "r");
    while(file != EOF){
        fread(buffer, 4, 4, file);
        printHex(buffer[counter]);
        counter++;
    }
    fclose(outname);
}
```

Comment: C or C++? Pick a language.

Comment: No... not `while(file != EOF)` but `while(fread(buffer, 4, 4, file) == 4)`

Comment: either one, this function is in C so that would be preferable

Comment: When you say hex file, do you mean 2 characters == 1 byte?

Comment: ...or should that be `while(fread(&buffer[counter], 4, 1, file) == 1)` ? (Edit ty @JohnyMopp). OP's version reads 16 bytes at a time, not 4.

Comment: If you are building the buffer: `fread(&buffer[counter], 4, 4, file)`

Comment: When you say _"a file which contains all hex values"_, do you _actually_ mean "a file whose bytes I like to look at in their hex-pair representation for convenience"? Or does it actually contain ASCII-encoded hex pairs? Or something else?

Comment: _"either one, this function is in C"_ So not either one. Please just tag _one_ language. C and C++ are distinct.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks that's what I was getting at but you articulated it much better.

Comment: You use the buffer to read the data starting at the beginning of the buffer. The printHex(buffer[counter] is undefined yet...  Use &buffer[counter] in your read statement

Comment: Do you know the difference between "binary file" and "file with ascii representation of binary data in hex syntax"? To ask differently, does your file look like "efffeab10034" of "0xef 0xff 0xea 0xb1 0x00 0x34" or completly unreadable?

Comment: Show the input file.

Answer (score 6):

There are two things wrong with your code. 
First, look up the usage of fread. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/
Your code is reading 4 blocks of 4 bytes. From your question, my thinking is you intended to read 1 block of 4 bytes.

Second, you are never advancing your buffer when reading, so it's always putting data into the buffer at the very start.

Third, your counter is only incrementing by 1 when you are "printing"; it should be incrementing by 4 (bytes).

Comment: So three things :P

Comment: 4) comparing `file` with `EOF` is bad.

Comment: (5) Not testing whether `fread()` worked and read what you requested it to read is a problem.

Comment: (6) `fclose(outname)` is bogus; it should be `fclose(file)`.

Comment: (7) Not testing whether `fopen()` succeeded is a bug.

Comment: (8) In my book (and with my default compiler options), unused variable `fileOutput` is a bug.

Comment: (9) Passing `buffer[counter]` to `printHex()` means that `printHex()` only gets a single character to play with.  It should probably be `printHex(&buffer[counter]);` though there may be more changes than that required — we can't see the prototype for the `printHex()` function so we don't know what's needed.

Comment: @SamKuiper: There isn't enough code in the question for anyone to be able to help you.  Note the number of amendments of varying degrees of severity that have been noted in the answer and comments.  You should not ignore warnings from your compiler — no modern C compiler (say from this millennium) would accept `fclose(outname)` without whingeing about it.  Your compiler knows more about C than you do.  If it warns, it is because it is sure you have a bug in your code.  Crank up the warnings to the maximum — and then get the code to compile cleanly (and don't try running before it is clean).